Windows local non-admin user account password change thru script
Either in cmd or PowerShell, I am lost at letting local users with standard user account to change their password by a script, similar to pressing ctrl-alt-delete -> change password...where it prompts users for current password and then prompt and confirm the new password.
I tried 'net user' and set-localuser without success. they both give Access denied error.
Can this be done so non-admin users can change their password locally or remotely on their own accounts with a script?
Thanks.

You would need to use NetAPI32.NetUserChangePassword from the Win32 API
I used to use passwd.exe from 1997, but I'm not sure you can still download it anywhere.
It seems I wrote a PowerShell script a while ago that does the same thing.
It's on GitHub: https://github.com/hahndorf/hacops/blob/master/Set-Password.ps1
either use:
Set-Password.ps1

and fill in the prompts, or
Set-Password.ps1 -userName "Peter" -oldPassword "foo" -NewPassword "bar"

